# Как реализована единая точка входа в Android-приложение и есть ли она?

Tags: java, android

В Java приложениях, как я понимаю, существует единая точка входа для всего приложения в виде метода `main`, но этого метода нет в Android-приложениях. Как реализована единая точка входа в Android-приложениях и есть ли она?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В андроид приложениях нет единой точки входа, как это делается например при помощи `main()`. Приложение может запускаться очень многими способами. Приложения, в зависимости от их функционала, могут состоять из разных компонент активити, сервисы.

"Обычным" способом, конечно же является точка входа через main активити, но она не всегда может быть единственной. Запуск того или иного компонента зависит от событий которые происходят в системе и от того, может ли приложение эти события обработать.

Например, сервис может "слушать" событие `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` и обработав его запуститься сразу после загрузки операционной системы и т.п. `Intent` и `BroadcastReceiver` в плане выбора точки входа в приложение представляют довольно широкие возможности.

Comment: Но разве перед всеми действиями приложения не будет вызван `Application#onCreate()`?

Comment: с точки зрения концептуального запуска приложения именно самой операционной системой, Вы конечно правы, но вот точка входа в само приложение, для дальнейшего выполнения его логики  зависит от событий вызвавших его

Answer (score 10):

Таки не соглашусь с @ЮрийСПб

С точки зрения GUI точкой входа является `Activity` промаркированная/обозначенная в манифесте как:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN/>
</intent-filter>
```

Именно она определяет какой `Activity` будет запущен, если ткнуть в иконку приложения.

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN)

Answer (score 6):

Для андроида используется класс `Application` и его метод `onCreate()`. При этом его надо прописать в манифесте.

Answer (score 3):

Любое `Activity` помечено флагами в `manifest` как

```
category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN
```

является точкой входа в приложение. Класс `Application` вызывается первым при запуске программы. Метод `onCreate` входит в жизненный цикл любого `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

Android-приложение модульное и может включать в себя service-ы, reciever-ы и прочие элементы, которые могут запускаться до activity или отдельно от них.

В зависимости от задачи вам может подойти простой вариант- *onCreate* метод Activity указанной как 
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN/>`
В случае того же receiver-а ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED это будет onRecieve.
В случае сервиса- метод *onCreate*.

В общем случае можно указать в манифесте класс приложения:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

И отнаследовать приложения от Application или аналогичного

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //ваши действия
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать класс, наследующийся от класса `Application`.
Переопределить в нем метод onCreate, не забыв вызвать метод родителя.
Этот метод отработает первым при открытии приложения.

В манифесте к тегу `application` нужно добавить параметр `name` с указанием вышеуказанного класса.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // делаем что-то
}
}

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```